# playing frequencies on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

Can someone help me use the `AudioQueue` services on the iPhone to play a certain frequency (say, 440 Hz)? I've looked at the documentation, but I can't seem to figure out quite how to do it. Apple's sample code also isn't helping me too much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/Developer/Examples/CoreAudio/SimpleSDK/DefaultOutputUnit` has a sample of how to play a tone at a given frequency and sample rate.

I basically copied the code (also using a bit from [this blog entry](http://michael.tyson.id.au/2008/11/04/using-remoteio-audio-unit/)) and it worked with basically no change on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't hard at all to do this. Take a look at the AudioQueue examples. If you look at the code to play back an audio file, you're going to just do that, except without actually reading a file.

You just divide the sampling rate by your frequency, calculate a sine wave, and feed those values into the audioqueue in your playback callback function.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is kinda lame, but if no one comes up with the real answer, you could just pre-record a sine wave and loop it.  If it's cut well, it should play just fine.  Of course this response would only work if you had only a few different frequencies to play.